# Samsung Galaxy Y Hangs up when connected and tethered with USB

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, tethering, usb-tethering, samsung-galaxy-y

I just purchased a new Samsung Galaxy Y and it works fine normally. But when I connect my mobile with USB the explorer works fine in "my computer", but my phone gets hung up such that nothing works on the phone. It behaves like it has no resources to work with, as though someone might have sucked all the RAM/Processor from the cell.

Please suggest what can be done in this case. I have tried clearing RAM before connecting to PC, but it did not help.